Is it possible / how to add new ios 18 effort level estimation value to a HealthKit workout builder?
I am working on a function that adds some of the workout data collected by my app to health kit, this is how it looks so far (simplified)
static func addWorkout(
    start: Date,
    end: Date
  ) async {
      let config = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
      config.activityType = .traditionalStrengthTraining


      // My Failed Attempt at adding effort level as a sample
      let effort = HKQuantitySample(
        type: HKQuantityType(.estimatedWorkoutEffortScore),
        quantity: .init(unit: .percent(), doubleValue: 50),
        start: start,
        end: end
      )

      let builder = HKWorkoutBuilder(healthStore: HealthKitStore, configuration: config, device: .local())
      do {
        try await builder.beginCollection(at: start)
        try await builder.addSamples([effort])
        try await builder.endCollection(at: end)
        try await builder.finishWorkout()
      } catch {
        // Error handling
      }
  }

I am trying to see if it is possible to add a sample of estimated effort level (new feature introduced in ios 18), above is what I tried so far. It doesn't error in XCode, but app crashes when trying to do it this way.
I am wondering if someone figured out if this is possible / how to add it to a workout. Thank you

    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - uuid: UUID of HKWorkout
    ///   - scoreInPercentage: Percentage value 0...1
    func scoreWorkout(uuid: UUID, scoreInPercentage: Double) async throws {
        if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
            // Get workout
            let workout = try await healthStore.fetchWorkout(uuid: uuid)
            // Set effort
            let effort = HKQuantitySample(
                type: HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .workoutEffortScore)!,
                quantity: HKQuantity(unit: .appleEffortScore(), doubleValue: scoreInPercentage * 10), // HKDiscreteQuantitySample appleEffortScore requires a value between 0 and 10
                start: workout.startDate,
                end: workout.endDate
            )
            // Update workout
            try await healthStore.relateWorkoutEffortSample(effort, with: workout, activity: nil)
        } else {
            logger.warning("workoutEffortScore available on iOS18+")
        }
    }


Thanks, this work! I'm just wondering can I read the effortScore somehow?
